# Setting JavaFX Anchor Pane's anchors in CSS

Tags: java, css, javafx, fxml

One of windows in my GUI application consists of similar HBoxes with same controls inside. I wanted to center everything in a top layer pane (in this case - Anchor Pane).

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <VBox fx:id="modeWindowPane" alignment="CENTER" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <children>
                <Label contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="100.0" text="Current" />
                <TextField prefWidth="100.0" />
                <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Set Current"/>
            </children>
        </HBox>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <children>
                <Label contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="100.0" text="Frequency" />
                <TextField prefWidth="100.0" />
                <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Set Current"/>
            </children>
        </HBox>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <children>
                <Label contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="100.0" text="Fade In" />
                <TextField prefWidth="100.0" />
                <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Set Current"/>
            </children>
        </HBox>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <children>
                <Label contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="100.0" text="Fade Out" />
                <TextField prefWidth="100.0" />
                <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Set Current"/>
            </children>
        </HBox>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <children>
                <Label contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="100.0" text="Offset" />
                <TextField prefWidth="100.0" />
                <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Set Current"/>
            </children>
        </HBox>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
            <Label contentDisplay="CENTER" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="100.0" text="Stimulation Time" />
            <TextField prefWidth="100.0" />
            <Button maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Set Current"/>
        </HBox>
    </VBox>
</AnchorPane>
```

You can see that in every HBox there are bottom/left/right/top anchors. I wanted to parametrize them somehow, set default HBox properties in my FXML file via CSS for example. But when I started looking for more info (tutorials, Oracle's references, Stack) I didn't find anything useful.

Can someone tell me if there is any way I wouldn't have to edit every component to, for example, align it in a way I want? Also, it has to be compliant with MVC design pattern.

Comment: The `HBox`es have a `VBox` as their parent: it doesn't make sense to set `AnchorPane` properties for them.

Comment: @James_D, in FXML, if there are Boxes in Anchor Pane, it is possible to add it's properties to them. They are more an alignment settings than a direct pane's properties.

Comment: But they are not (directly) in the `AnchorPane`. They are in a `VBox`.

Comment: In general, in JavaFX, CSS is used to define styles, not layout. Layout properties should be set in FXML. But it's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here: probably using an appropriate [layout pane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/builtin_layouts.htm#JFXLY102) would be better than using an `AnchorPane` here.

Comment: @James_D: I used StackPane instead of the AnchorPane. Now everything works as I wanted it to. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at 
[JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html). There you find the complete documentary of all CSS attributes. As far as I know you can't set the anchor's for an object via CSS.

You can make it via the Controller. Just give all items a `fx:id` an assign them in your Controller. Then you can iterate over them and set the Anchors (e.g. `AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(Node, Value)`). For further information see [AnchorPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html).

Comment: Thank you, but I know this reference. I've read it and I'm afraid what you're saying is unfortunately true. I'm aware it is possible via the Controller. But I wanted to design my project in a MVC design pattern way and I'm not sure if editing layout in Controller is allowed.